# pytest cannot locate dynamically created module

Tags: python, import, python-3.7

I have a directory structure like what follows:

package_root/lib/package_name/foo.py

in foo.py I have a function that creates a file (bar.py) that contains a function (f). foo.py also has a function that then imports bar and runs bar.f().

When I state, within foo.py "import bar", it works, and I have access to bar.f and it runs just fine.

However, this is not the case when running pytest. We run pytest from package_root and it cannot find the module bar when it attempts to import it. This is because (I believe) when running pytest, it creates bar.py in /package_root which contains no **init**.py file. Since our tests run automatically for our cicd pipeline, I need it to be able to properly import when running pytest from package_root. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pythonis a *very* dynamic language. What it your use case to create a module dynamically that can't be done in an other way?

Comment: the function body (of f) is a string obtained from a db entry and I need to be able to dynamically create a function that can take arguments passed to it and then call said function. Sometimes these function bodies will return a boolean, other times they will return the result of another function call using the argument passed into f as the argument passed into the function call that is in the function body.

Comment: Then I hope you have as much trust in your database as you have in your code. This sound like a recipe for a security disaster.

Comment: Patch (mock) the `foo.import_bar_and_call_f` function.

Comment: the answer was to use tempfile and use importlib.utils.spec_from_file_location, importlib.utils.module_from_spec and spec.loader.exec_module

Answer (score 0):

As far as I comprehend from your question is that you are facing imports issue in your pipeline(Correct me if am wrong). In pytest, normally your framework should contain the **pytest.ini/tox.ini** along with all the test scripts. Please refer link(http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html).

Create a file pytest.ini/tox.ini in your framework design from where you are running your code(in your case in the package_root/ directory).

```
#pytest.ini
[pytest]
python_paths = . lib/<package-name>/
```